# Foundation Joyride issues

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

I am trying to use Foundation's joyride in my website. I took the example on Zurbs homepage like this

```
<ol class="joyride-list" data-joyride>
<li data-id="firstStop" data-text="Next" data-options="tip_location: top; prev_button: false">
    <p>Hello and welcome to the Joyride <br>documentation page.</p>
</li>
<li data-id="numero1" data-class="custom so-awesome" data-text="Next" data-prev-text="Prev">
    <h4>Stop #1</h4>
    <p>You can control all the details for you tour stop. Any valid HTML will work inside of Joyride.</p>
</li>
<li data-id="numero2" data-button="Next" data-prev-text="Prev" data-options="tip_location:top;tip_animation:fade">
    <h4>Stop #2</h4>
    <p>Get the details right by styling Joyride with a custom stylesheet!</p>
</li>
<li data-button="End" data-prev-text="Prev">
    <h4>Stop #3</h4>
    <p>It works as a modal too!</p>
</li>
```

and then in the javsScript I initialize it like this

```
$(document).foundation('joyride', 'start');
```

I get this error on my console,

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Any explanations on how I am getting this error?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `$(document).foundation();` code? Do you still get the error?

Comment: yes then it removes the error.

Comment: Are you including an element with `id="firstStop"` so the Joyride has an element to attach to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the page is missing an element for Joyride to attach to. Your code contains the JoyRide modals but doesn't contain an element to attach to.

Add

```
<div id="firstStop">First Stop</div>
```

to your HTML.

Here's a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/sz41748j/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was missing.